# React Native : How can I create two TouchableOpacity components that swap height and width values when pressed?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want one of the images to be slightly larger than the other when pressed and viceVersa. I am trying to use useState to achieve this but I couldn't do it. I have attached an image below for your reference. Thank you! [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming only those 2 options, you can use state to set the value of blurred. and toggle the heights for the buttons base on the value of blurred

```
import React ,{useState}from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default function App() {
  let [blur ,setBlur] = useState(true)
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity 
      onPress={()=>{setBlur(true)}}
      style={{ ...styles.button, backgroundColor:"red"  , height: blur ? 60 : 40 }}>
        <Text>Blurred</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity 
      onPress={()=>{setBlur(false)}}
      style={{...styles.button, backgroundColor:"blue"  , height: blur ? 40 : 60 }} >
        <Text>Default</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    alignItems: "center",
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },  

  button: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems:"center",
    paddingVertical: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 30

  }
});
```